# 'possess of' vs 'possess with' vs 'possess + another preposition'?

Tags: difference

> [A.](http://www.cbc.ca/thenational/blog/2012/06/what-to-do-when-the-police-want-to-talk-to-you.html)  If you can prove your innocence, or you want to give an account, you can do that in your lawyer's office. If you have concrete evidence, then give it to your lawyer. He or she can provide the evidence to the police or Crown and deal with them on an equal footing, **possessed of** complete rather than selective information.
>
> **[possess](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/possess)** [with object] = 1.2 Have as an ability, quality, or characteristic: ...
> **(be possessed of)** a fading blonde possessed of a powerful soprano voice

I see and so ask NOT about the definition, which I instead want to burrow into. What are the similarities and differences? Does **be possessed with** mean the same? What other prepositions could be used after **possess**? Is **be possessed of** the only choice of preposition?

Answer (score 1):

I think the adjective "possessed" with the preposition "of" and "with" are used in different senses, hence not interchangeable. As you know, we use "possessed of" to mean to have or own, and we use possessed with/by" to mean that somebody is under the power or influence of a strong emotion, desire or a spirit. Nor do we have any other option of any other preposition but to use "of" in the context of the sentence presented.

Although, The Free Dictionary says that "possessed" (followed by "of") is also used to mean to be influenced by a strong emotion or spirit, I think it is rarely used in this sense).